# Cannot delete meeting confirmation email - "The operation failed. An object could not be found."

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I am using Outlook 2007. This morning I created a meeting and sent an invite to the other participant. He accepted my meeting and I got an acceptance email. When I try to delete this email Outlook gives me the following error:

> The operation failed. An object could not be found.

Here is what I've tried, to no avail:

- Closed and reopened Outlook
- Deleted the meeting from my calendar

How do I get this out of my Inbox?

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found here.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312354

To resolve this behavior, create a new profile. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Click Start, point to Settings, and then click Control Panel.
2. Double-click the Mail icon.
3. In the Mail Setup dialog box, click Show Profiles.

   If you want to be able to select a specific profile each time you start Outlook, click the General tab, click Prompt for a profile to be used, and then click Add.
4. In the New Profile dialog box, under Profile Name, type a descriptive name for the new profile, and then click OK.
5. In the E-mail Accounts dialog box, select Add a new e-mail account in the e-mail options, and then click Next.
6. Click the type of server that your e-mail account works with, and then click Next.
7. Complete all of the required fields, including those that are on the tabs that appear after you click More Settings.
8. When you finish providing the required information, click Finish.

Comment: I don't think that's it. The article you cite refers to getting this error when sending or receiving email. Outlook can send/receive without issue.